# Call powershell script with libraries using C++

Tags: c++, powershell

I have a powershell script called "email.ps1" with the following code:

```
$env:PSModulePath = $env:PSModulePath + ";C:\TMP\codigos\powershell\libraries"

. library.ps1

. inithialize.ps1

(...)
```

And im trying to call it with a C++ program using the system command. Unfortunately, the program cant find the libraries "library" and "inithialize", but it does work when i call the script using powershell/cmd without the C++ program.

I've already tried these calls without success

```
system("full_path_to_script/email.ps1")
system("powershell full_path_to_script/email.ps1")
system("powershell.exe full_path_to_script/email.ps1")
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you able to launch Powershell at all? What's the execution policy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are dot sourcing the `library.ps1` and `inithialize.ps1` scripts and not importing them as modules using [`Import-Module`](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh849725.aspx). So modifying the `PSModulePath` variable will have no effect since that is only used by Import-Module.

When dot-sourcing, you will need to include the full path, like so:

```
. C:\TMP\codigos\powershell\libraries\library.ps1
. C:\TMP\codigos\powershell\libraries\inithialize.ps1
```

Alternatively, you can turn these libraries into bona-fide PowerShell modules. Take a look at [the help on msdn for doing so](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878340%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the import-module link. I've done some tests with it and its very usefull !